# Django ORM how to return a grouped random query set

Tags: python, django-orm

I need to return a set of random groups in one query set. For example I currently have the following data set returned:

```
ID  Identity  Name

 1     E       Foo

 4     S       Bar

 2     E       Ted

 3     S       Bob

 5     S       Jen
```

I need to group the Identity column so that 'E' and 'S' are returned together but in random order each time. IE:

**Query 1:**

```
ID  Identity  Name

 1     E       Foo

 2     E       Ted

 4     S       Bar

 3     S       Bob

 5     S       Jen
```

And if I were to run it again:

**Query 2:**

```
ID  Identity  Name

 2     E       Ted

 1     E       Foo

 4     S       Bar

 5     S       Jen

 3     S       Bob
```

I am not sure if this is possible using Django ORM functionality. Please advise. Thanks in advance as I am a little new to Django. Also, I am aware that I can send a Raw query in and get results. I would like to try to avoid this if possible. If not, I understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I belive you can't do this in a queryset, but you can use random module from python and sort by identity after:</strike>

```
import random
objects = list(queryset)
random.shuffle(objects)
objects.sort(key=lambda x: x.Identity)
```

In fact, like specified in the 
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by), you can order by random.

try something like this:

```
queryset.order_by('Identity', '?')
```

Comment: Ill give it a try. Hopefully effecient with around 2000 records. Thanks!